# php simplexml find text of html tag inside xml element

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

How do I set a php variable to everything inside the `<STRONG>` tag below in the xml:

```
<SAVED_EXPORT>
    <metatag_description>
    Some text here? The &lt;strong&gt; Cambro High-Impact 12" x 16" Dietary Tray&lt;/strong&gt; is the solution. Comprised of high-impact, ligh
    </metatag_description>
</SAVED_EXPORT>

<?    foreach( $xml as $SAVED_EXPORT ) {

        $header = $SAVED_EXPORT->metadescription;
        echo $header[0];
        } 
?>
```

I want it to just spit out: **Cambro High-Impact 12" x 16" Dietary Tray** instead of all the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following expression instead of your echo:

```
if (preg_match("/\&lt\;strong\&gt\;(.*?)\&lt\;\/strong\&gt\;/si", $header[0], $match) == true)
{
    echo $match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strpos and substr:

```
$string = 'Some text here? The &lt;strong&gt; Cambro High-Impact 12" x 16" Dietary     Tray&lt;/strong&gt; is the solution. Comprised of high-impact, ligh'; 

// Tag to look for
$tag       = 'strong';
$start_tag = '&lt;' . $tag . '&gt;';
$end_tag   = '&lt;/' . $tag . '&gt;';

// Determine position of search pattern <strong>
$begin = strpos($string, $start_tag);
// Add the lenght of the tag string:
$begin += strlen($start_tag);
// Determine position of search pattern </strong>
$end   = strpos($string, $end_tag);
// Calculate length:
$length = $end - $begin;

// echo the trimmed substring
echo trim(substr($string, $begin, $length));
```

Comment: This example is more dynamic, as it traverses through the string to find the starting position. However, it is less dynamic because it assumes the programmer knows the length of the string.

Comment: @nodirtyrockstar - well then, a little more dynamic now. thanks for the input!